# VBA SumIfs range object

Tags: excel, vba, range, sumifs

I'm trying to build a macro to create a table based on SumIfs formula with 2 criteria. The Rows are the criteria 1, the Columns are the criteria 2. The result of the SumIfs is the table. I ask the user the range of criteria 1, criteria 2 and the sum in the sheet (StrSheetName), and I build the result in another sheet.

The part that doesn't work, I believe it's related to the range object:

```
Cells(cellposY, cellPosX).Value = wf.SumIfs(sumRange, Criteria1, Worksheets("SumIfTable").Cells(cellposY, 2).Value, Criteria2, Worksheets("SumIfTable").Cells(2, cellPosX).Value)
```

EDIT:

That's my test table (the input data):

[image]

That's what I trying to do:

[image]

The complete code:

```
Dim InputRangeCritY As Range
Dim InputRangeCritX As Range
Dim InputSumValue As Range

Dim temp As Variant

Set InputRangeCritY = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select first criteria/column, would be displayed in Y :", Type:=8)
Set InputRangeCritX = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select second criteria/column, would be displayed in X :", Type:=8)
Set InputSumValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select sum valued, will be use for the sumif formula :", Type:=8)

InputRangeCritY.Select
Selection.Copy

Dim StrSheetName As String
StrSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

Sheets.Add.Name = "SumIfTable"
Worksheets("SumIfTable").Activate
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B3").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Worksheets(StrSheetName).Activate
InputRangeCritX.Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("SumIfTable").Activate
Range("D3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D3").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Range("D3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Range("D3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim OutputRangeCritY As Range
Dim OutputRangeCritX As Range

Range("B3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set OutputRangeCritY = Selection

Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Set OutputRangeCritX = Selection

Dim cellPosX As Long
Dim cellposY As Long
cellPosX = 3
cellposY = 3

Set sumRange = Worksheets(StrSheetName).Range(InputSumValue.Address)
Set Criteria1 = Worksheets(StrSheetName).Range(InputRangeCritY.Address)
Set Criteria2 = Worksheets(StrSheetName).Range(InputRangeCritX.Address)
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

Dim i As Long
Dim J As Long
J = OutputRangeCritY.Cells.Count

Dim g As Long
Dim H As Long
H = OutputRangeCritX.Cells.Count

For g = 1 To H
    For i = 1 To J
        Cells(cellposY, cellPosX).Value = wf.SumIfs(sumRange, Criteria1, Worksheets("SumIfTable").Cells(cellposY, 2).Value, Criteria2, Worksheets("SumIfTable").Cells(2, cellPosX).Value)
        cellposY = cellposY + 1
    Next
    cellPosX = cellPosX + 1
Next
```

Comment: First thing to check is that the sum and criteria ranges are the same size.

Comment: They are, I build a small table with test data to test my macro.

Comment: the criteria must be the same shape and size.  one cannot use a row and a column as the criteria.  Please share your test table and what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Why not do a pivot table?

Comment: The input that I want to use is really big, I want a method to create that table without formula/ pivot table. When the code will work I will replace each cell by the value instead of the formula. The output table will be easier to manipulate.

Comment: I tried the pivot table, and as I expected the output table isn't what I want. I'm doing an analysis for a year, day by day for thousands of items.

Comment: What exactly is your issue with a pivot table?  The two differences I see from your desired results are the labelling in the row above the row where the column headers (dates) are shown; and the fact that there are blanks instead of zeros in some of the cells.

Comment: For this short table, Pivot table would work fine, but for large table Pivot table don't give me the sorting I want. Also, I prefer number instead of formula or pivot table because the file is less heavy.